# Python - How to split string into an array while ignoring inner arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have a string that looks similar to the following:

```py
string = "hello,2,test,1,[4,something,3],1,2"
```

When I split the string by commas I get the following array:

```py
['hello', '2', 'test', '1', '[4', 'something', '3]', '1', '2']
```

How could I efficiently split the original string to instead get the following:

```py
['hello', '2', 'test', '1', '[4,something,3]', '1', '2']
```

Comment: Can '[...]' strings be nested, like '[a, b, [c, d], e]'?

Comment: Are you eventually trying to turn this into `['hello', 2, 'test', 1, [4, 'something', 3], 1, 2]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex

`import re
re.split(r",\s*(?![^[]*])",string)`

Result:

`['hello', '2', 'test', '1', '[4,something,3]', '1', '2']`

Note this answer assumes no nested []

Comment: This fails for `hello,2,test,1,[4,something,3],1,2,[4,[something],3]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```py
string = "hello,2,test,1,[4,something,3],1,2"
string2 = string.split(",")
res = []
temp = []
found = False

for item in string2:
    if (not(found)):
        if "[" in item:
            found = True
            temp = []
            temp.append(item[1:])
        else:
            res.append(item)

    else:
        if "]" in item:
            found = False
            temp.append(item[:-1])
            final = str(temp).replace("'", "")
            res.append(final)
        else:
            temp.append(item)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
['hello', '2', 'test', '1', '[4, something, 3]', '1', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```py
import re

string = "hello,2,test,1,[4,something,3],1,2"
x = re.findall(r'\[[^\]]+\](?=,|\b)|[^,]+(?=,|\b)', string)
```

x contains `['hello', '2', 'test', '1', '[4,something,3]', '1', '2']`.

In the regex we have two cases separated by `|` (or). The first should handle the longer cases `[something, in, brackets]` the second can handle the simple cases. In case you are not familiar with it `(?=,|\b)` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).